# How do I dynamically update a web page with output from a shell script?

Tags: shell, web

I have a unix shell script generating output over time that I would like to pipe to a web page which would display it as it appears.

Is there a simple way to do this?  I have tried "Transfer-Encoding: chunked" which doesn't work and AJAX which is not so simple.  Thanks.

Comment: Please explain in more detail.  What do you mean by "would display it as it appears"?  Do you mean that the content of the web page would just keep growing forever?  Would old output disappear after a while?  Should the page auto-reload or would the user have to specifically refresh it?

Comment: The web page would grow forever, the old content would not scroll away.  Preferably, the page would not have to reload, characters would just appear as they become available from the shell script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple way: If you save the output to a text file, somewhere within your website, you could embed it in an iframe. You could then use JavaScript in the parent page to reload the iframe periodically, or an HTTP refresh if you can't use script.

A more elegant solution would be to use something like `jQuery.get()` to check for updates and write them to the page. Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/S9nYE/1/ (the fiddle doesn't do much, as it isn't pointed at a real file, but I've tested the code on my webserver).

How to set it up: have your command output to a file, say `log.txt` in your web root, put the fiddle code into an HTML file in the same folder, and edit `var fileToCheck = "log.txt"` (or whatever the file is called). Then, load the HTML file in a browser. Change `checkInterval` to alter the speed of updates.

Either way, be careful that if this command might give away details of your system, that the webpage is appropriately locked down. If it's sensitive, it may be easier and safer to ssh into your system and `tail -f logfile`.

Comment: "If you want an example, leave a comment, and I can edit one in."  Yes please.

Comment: Added a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/S9nYE/1/ - let me know how that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

You could just make the raw output file available on your website or over an api call and then write a small html/javascript page that can query the output file over AJAX and insert it into the page.

Answer (score 0):

`Transfer-Encoding: Chunked` is what you need however you also need to ensure that the web-server has compression disabled as well; although it's meant to work with compression, I couldn't get a chunked encoding and mod_deflate to play well together with Apache -- this is something I bumped into with a Perl CGI that feeds data out continuously; it involved placing `Set-Env no-gzip 1` into `.htaccess` for the folder my CGI lives in.

If in doubt, start a Wireshark trace and try to see exactly what's coming over the wire.

The only other thing to mention is to ensure your script is not buffering output. If this is a bash/ksh/*sh script, then you might need to override the buffer with the `stdbuf` command (part of coreutils; [this is a good primer](http://www.pixelbeat.org/programming/stdio_buffering/) on controlling buffering).

If you're writing this in Perl make sure it's unbuffered with `$|=1`.

Once you know what's coming over the wire, you'll get an idea whether its the script or the web-server (or both!) that you need to tweak.